# R "by" function returning NULL values when paired with self-created "nrow" function

Tags: r, function, subset

I have literally spent >3 hours trying to troubleshoot this issue. I am trying to get counts of instances for each id. I created my own function within the "by" function and I tested the function and it gets me the correct count for all ids combined... but it returns "NULL" when I run the below code:

To make it a more applied concept.. what if I want to know how many "well" + "lab" visits each patient has had at my facility. :

```
dataset #<- this is the name of my dataset; each row is a visit.
id #<- this is the unique ID for each patient
event #<- this variable tells what type of visit it was

event == 1 #this is a 'well' visit
event == 2 #this is a lab visit 
event == 3 #this is a sick visit
event == 4 #this is an urgent care visit

by(dataset[,"event"], dataset[,"id"], function(dataset) {
nrow(subset(dataset["event"], (dataset["event"]==1 | dataset["event"]==2)))})
```

As it is, when I separate the function
`nrow(subset(dataset["event"], (dataset["event"]==1 | dataset["event"]==2)))`

from the `by` statement, I get a total count of these types of visit for ALL of the patients. When I run the code including the `by` statement, I get the separation by `id`, but NULL values. I am pretty sure that the issue is something missing from my `function()` code...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table(subset(dataset, event %in% c(1, 2))$id)
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you! I will be able to get some work done today and will not sprout any more gray hairs!